# Console mouse events in Windows 10

Tags: c, winapi

The purpose of this program is to use the mouse on the output console.

I used this code in C and it worked on Windows 7. What should I change to make it work on Windows 10?  The mouse doesn't react on Windows 10.
Maybe a library is missing? Maybe library `windows` is not supported by Windows 10?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

HANDLE hStdin;                     
DWORD fdwSaveOldMode;               

DWORD cNumRead, fdwMode, i;        
INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[128];

VOID MouseEventProc(MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD mer)
{
    switch(mer.dwEventFlags)
    {
        case 0:

            if(mer.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
            {
                mer.dwMousePosition.X;
                mer.dwMousePosition.Y;
                printf("left button press   posX  %d\n", mer.dwMousePosition.X);
            }
            else if(mer.dwButtonState == RIGHTMOST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
            {
                printf("right button press \n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("button press\n");
            }
            break;
    }
}

int main(VOID)
{
    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ErrorExit("GetStdHandle");
    
    if (! GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &fdwSaveOldMode) ) ErrorExit("GetConsoleMode");
    
    fdwMode = ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT;
    if (! SetConsoleMode(hStdin, fdwMode) ) ErrorExit("SetConsoleMode");

    while(1)
    {
        if (! ReadConsoleInput(
                hStdin,      
                irInBuf,     
                1,         
                &cNumRead) ) ErrorExit("ReadConsoleInput");

        i=0;     
        switch(irInBuf[i].EventType)
        {
            case MOUSE_EVENT: // mouse input
                MouseEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.MouseEvent);
                break;
        }
    }

    SetConsoleMode(hStdin,fdwSaveOldMode);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm lost because it is very important to me.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the functionality you use? What does it say about Windows versions above 7?

Comment: Code and doc provided by MSDN . But I see nothing about Windows versions. as it's a console mouse use, I'm afraid there hasn't been an adaptation yet maybe later. I don't now.

Comment: And I try on Win10 and 11 , same problem, nothing is displayed on the screen, not even a flicker which would indicate an intercepted event.

Comment: It depends on current console settings. Right click in Console upper left corner, click on "Properties", "Options" tab, and uncheck "QuickEdit Mode". Programmatically you can do `fdwMode = (fdwSaveOldMode | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT) & ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE;` to force this